# Minikube crashes exec'ing into Pod using Alpine linux

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Everytime I try and exec into a pod through the minikube dashboard running alpine linux it crashes and closes the connection with the following error

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"

CONNECTION CLOSED
```

Output from the command "kubectl version" reads as follows:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", 
GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", 
GitVersion:"v1.8.0", 
GitCommit:"0b9efaeb34a2fc51ff8e4d34ad9bc6375459c4a4", 
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-29T22:43:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Can anybody please advise? I can run other containers perfectly OK as long as they have BASH not ASH.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally Alpine linux doesn't contain bash.
Have you tried executing into the container with any of the following?

```
/bin/ash

/bin/sh

ash

sh
```

so for example `kubectl exec -it my-alpine-shell-293fj2fk-fifni2 -- sh` should do the job.

Comment: Apologies, I am exec'ing into the pod using the minikube dashboard. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

> Everytime I try and exec into a pod

You didn't specify the command you provided to `kubectl exec` but based on your question I'm going to assume it is `kubectl exec -it $pod -- bash`

The problem, as the error message states, is that the container image you are using does not provide bash. Many, many "slim" images don't ship with `bash` because of the dependencies doing so would bring with them.

If you want a command that works across all images, use `sh`, since 90% of the time if `bash` is present, it is symlinked to `/bin/sh` and the other cases (as you mentioned with `ash` or `dash` or whatever) then using `sh` will still *work* and allow you to determine if you need to adjust the command to specifically request a different shell.

Thus `kubectl exec -it $pod -- sh` is the command I would expect to work

Comment: Apologies, I am exec'ing into the pod using the minikube dashboard. I have updated the question

Comment: Well, then don't do that; the dashboard isn't designed to be a replacement for `kubectl`. If you insist on using the dashboard, then I would suggest creating a new docker image (using your alpine image as the `FROM` line) that _does_ contain `bash` and deploy that.